# multi-class confusion matrix to calculate with-in class error

Tags: r, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I have tried k-NN classification using the toy data and got the  predictions as below:

```
actual <- c(rep('A1',12), rep('A2',12), rep('A3',7), rep('A4',12), rep('B1',11), rep('B2',17), rep('C1',15))
prediction <- c('A1','A1','A1','A1','A1','A3','A4','A4','B1','B2','C1','C1',
                'A2','A2','A2','A2','A2','A3','A4','A4','A4','B1','B1','C1',
                'A1','A2','A3','A3','A3','A3','B2',
                'A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A4','A4','A4','A4','A4','A4','B1',
                'A1','A2','A2','A4','B1','B1','B1','B2','B2','B2','B2',
                'A1','A3','B1','B1','B1','B1','B2','B2','B2','B2','B2','B2','B2','B2','B2','C1','C1',
                'A1','A1','A2','B2','B2','C1','C1','C1','C1','C1','C1','C1','C1','C1','C1')
```

Basic idea about the predictions can be achieved using the `table()` as:

```
table(actual, prediction)
#       prediction
# actual A1 A2 A3 A4 B1 B2 C1
#     A1  5  0  1  2  1  1  2
#     A2  0  5  1  3  2  0  1
#     A3  1  1  4  0  0  1  0
#     A4  2  3  0  6  1  0  0
#     B1  1  2  0  1  3  4  0
#     B2  1  0  1  0  4  9  2
#     C1  2  1  0  0  0  2 10
```

There is a much informative function `caret::confusionMatrix()`.

```
caret::confusionMatrix(prediction, actual)
# Confusion Matrix and Statistics
# 
# Reference
# Prediction A1 A2 A3 A4 B1 B2 C1
# A1  5  0  1  2  1  1  2
# A2  0  5  1  3  2  0  1
# A3  1  1  4  0  0  1  0
# A4  2  3  0  6  1  0  0
# B1  1  2  0  1  3  4  0
# B2  1  0  1  0  4  9  2
# C1  2  1  0  0  0  2 10
# 
# Overall Statistics
# 
# Accuracy : 0.4884         
# 95% CI : (0.379, 0.5986)
# No Information Rate : 0.1977         
# P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1.437e-09      
# 
# Kappa : 0.3975         
# Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA             
# 
# Statistics by Class:
# 
#                      Class: A1 Class: A2 Class: A3 Class: A4 Class: B1 Class: B2 Class: C1
# Sensitivity            0.41667   0.41667   0.57143   0.50000   0.27273    0.5294    0.6667
# Specificity            0.90541   0.90541   0.96203   0.91892   0.89333    0.8841    0.9296
# Pos Pred Value         0.41667   0.41667   0.57143   0.50000   0.27273    0.5294    0.6667
# Neg Pred Value         0.90541   0.90541   0.96203   0.91892   0.89333    0.8841    0.9296
# Prevalence             0.13953   0.13953   0.08140   0.13953   0.12791    0.1977    0.1744
# Detection Rate         0.05814   0.05814   0.04651   0.06977   0.03488    0.1047    0.1163
# Detection Prevalence   0.13953   0.13953   0.08140   0.13953   0.12791    0.1977    0.1744
# Balanced Accuracy      0.66104   0.66104   0.76673   0.70946   0.58303    0.7067    0.7981
```

I have observed that there are many subclasses belong to another class. For example, `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `A4` belong to class `A`. Similarly `B1`, `B2` belong to class `B`. I would like to calculate the statistics after treating all the subclasses within a class as equal. Is there any function available to generate similar statistics as above for within class and out-class errors?

**Note:** Please do not propose solutions which contain removing the numbers from the subclasses, as the real application is not similar to this. For simplicity purpose, I have given this example.

Is it possible to take get the solution if the class and subclass relations are given?

Answer (score 1):

How about defining the classes manually by removing the subclass suffix:

```
    actual <- c(rep('A1',12), rep('A2',12), rep('A3',7), rep('A4',12), rep('B1',11), rep('B2',17), rep('C1',15))
    prediction <- c('A1','A1','A1','A1','A1','A3','A4','A4','B1','B2','C1','C1',
                    'A2','A2','A2','A2','A2','A3','A4','A4','A4','B1','B1','C1',
                    'A1','A2','A3','A3','A3','A3','B2',
                    'A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A4','A4','A4','A4','A4','A4','B1',
                    'A1','A2','A2','A4','B1','B1','B1','B2','B2','B2','B2',
                    'A1','A3','B1','B1','B1','B1','B2','B2','B2','B2','B2','B2','B2','B2','B2','C1','C1',
                    'A1','A1','A2','B2','B2','C1','C1','C1','C1','C1','C1','C1','C1','C1','C1')
    actual = gsub("\\d", "", actual)
    prediction = gsub("\\d", "", prediction)
    caret::confusionMatrix(prediction, actual)

#output
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  A  B  C
         A 34  6  3
         B  6 20  2
         C  3  2 10

Overall Statistics

               Accuracy : 0.7442          
                 95% CI : (0.6387, 0.8322)
    No Information Rate : 0.5             
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 3.272e-06       

                  Kappa : 0.5831          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 1               

Statistics by Class:

                     Class: A Class: B Class: C
Sensitivity            0.7907   0.7143   0.6667
Specificity            0.7907   0.8621   0.9296
Pos Pred Value         0.7907   0.7143   0.6667
Neg Pred Value         0.7907   0.8621   0.9296
Prevalence             0.5000   0.3256   0.1744
Detection Rate         0.3953   0.2326   0.1163
Detection Prevalence   0.5000   0.3256   0.1744
Balanced Accuracy      0.7907   0.7882   0.7981
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, I forgot to mention not to use this approach, as the real data is not similar to this. It is not possible to remove the data in a pattern like you have proposed.

Comment: One can still define `if (class %in% c(subclass1, subclass2, subclass3)) "A" else {if (class %in% c(subclass4, subclass4, subclass5)) "B"...`

Comment: But still, it is not possible to calculate the within-class error statistics?

Comment: How would you tell caret or any supervised learning model that something is a subclass of a certain class if not providing a vector of classes which is the same length as the vector of sub-classes? On another note, I would rerun kNN again with classes and not sub-classes, and select the optimum k. There's a change the prediction error will be lower than if you take the current road.

Comment: Yes, I do not want to recode the variables completely. I need to calculate with-in class and out-of class errors. With just recoding, I would not get the statistics similar to the above?

Comment: How would you define with-in class errors? If say you have class A with sub-classes A1, A2 and A3 in the actual vector and in the prediction vector you have a mix of A1, A2, A3, B2 and C1, some A1 are predicted to be A1, some A3 and some B2 etc. Only way I see is to do 1 vs all for all sub-classes in order to calculate with-in class errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155028/discussion-between-prradep-and-missuse).